# C++ "'__gthread_active_p' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw

I'm getting GCC compiling on windows with std::atomic and std::thread support.
I'm using mingw from here: http://winlibs.com/

I'm building with this command:

```
g++.exe @CMakeFiles/StrFormatsJSONTest.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -latomic -lglu32 -lopengl32 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600 -DWINVER=0x600 -D_WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -g -std=gnu++2a -o main.cpp.obj -c main.cpp
```

However, when using `#include <atomic>` the following error occurs:

```
[build] c:\utils\bin\mingw32\include\c++\10.3.0\ext\atomicity.h:83:9: error: '__gthread_active_p' was not declared in this scope
[build]    83 |     if (__gthread_active_p())
```

If I define the function manually, I get a multiple definition error (so clearly it in the project somehow).

I'm including threads using:

```
    find_package( Threads )
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} )
```

I'm including `latomic` using:

```
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -latomic -lglu32 -lopengl32 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600 -DWINVER=0x600 -D_WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -D__GTHREADS=1")
```

^ Like this because I need it in ALL targets within the project.

The library states that the function should be present if GTHREADS macro is 1:

[image]

Clearly it is, thats where the error is:

[image]

When I add a definition (weakly linked) before `#include <atomic>` it works... But I get other errors such as:

```
error: '__gthread_once_t' does not name a type; did you mean '__gthread_active_p'?
```

For some reason GCC isn't including any one of these:

1. gthr-default.h
2. gthr-posix.h
3. gthr-single.h

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, I had a file called "Signal.h" it was being included instead of GCC's <signal.h>

More info, this is an issue on windows due to case insensitive filenames.